# Wait for one property to initialize and use it as reference for pulling data from db into another property, best practice?

Tags: swift, inheritance

I have a class, it has two properties:

1. `var fruitsPackId: Int`
2. `var fruitsPackContent: Array<Fruit>?`

Once the class is being initialized, I want to append data into `fruintsPackContent` from a local db according the the initialized `fruitsPackId`. I am not sure what is the best practice on that type of case.

What I did for now, is creating `fruitsPackContent` as a computed property, that pulls out the data from the local db using the `fruitsPackId` as reference id.

However, I feel that this is just not the right way of doing it, any ideas?

My code:

```
class FruitsPack: NSObject {

    var fruitsPackId: Int

    init(fruitsPackId: Int) {
        self.fruitsPackId = fruitsPackId
    }

    var fruitsPackContent: Array<Fruit>? {

        // Pulling data from local db here...
        // For this example I create a dummy array with one instance of Fruit
        let fruit1 = Fruit(fruitsPackId: self.fruitsPackId, fruitName: "Banana")
        var fruits = Array<Fruit>()
        fruits.append(fruit1)

        return fruits
    }
}

class Fruit: FruitsPack {

    var fruitName: String

    init(fruitsPackId: Int, fruitName: String) {
        self.fruitName = fruitName
        super.init(fruitsPackId: fruitsPackId)
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Using lazy variable type did the work for me:

- Class initialization has nothing to do with that property
- Memory is being utilized only once property is being called
- The property is being filled up with data only once
- An instance method is available to be used by others

New code:

```
class FruitsPack: NSObject {

    var fruitsPackId: Int
    lazy var fruitsPackContent: Array<Fruit>? = self.getFruitsPackContent(self.fruitsPackId)

    init(fruitsPackId: Int) {
        self.fruitsPackId = fruitsPackId
    }

    func getFruitsPackContent(fruitsPackId: Int) -> Array<Fruit>? {
        // Pulling data from local db here...
        // For this example I create a dummy array with one instance of Fruit
        let fruit1 = Fruit(fruitsPackId: self.fruitsPackId, fruitName: "Banana")
        var fruits = Array<Fruit>()
        fruits.append(fruit1)

        return fruits
    }
}

class Fruit: FruitsPack {

    var fruitName: String

    init(fruitsPackId: Int, fruitName: String) {
        self.fruitName = fruitName
        super.init(fruitsPackId: fruitsPackId)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Retrieving data from a database is a relatively computationally expensive process, so I'm not personally a fan of building that into a computed property. What if you innocently had some code that did the following:

```
for index in 0 ..< fruitPack.fruitsPackContent.count { 
    print(fruitPack.fruitsPackContent[index])
}
```

If you had *n* items in the database, this code might be repeatedly retrieving the full list of all items from the database *n + 1* times (once for `count` and again for each subscripted access). You could, theoretically, remedy this by making sure that the computed property cached the results (and you'd have to build some code that would identify when the database was updated and invalidate the cache).

It would be more prudent to make the retrieval from the database an explicit method so that the app developer knows when they're retrieving data from the database, and when they're accessing a cached array. You generally want to avoid some significant hidden performance impact resulting from innocently accessing some property.

Comment: I get the main direction, however, fruitsPackContent is empty to begin with, so count will be zero until I added some objects to fruitsPackContent. Logically OOP thinking, if I need to pull data from the db as soon as FruitsPack class is being initiated, where would be the right location in the code?

Comment: Fine, the first time you call it, `count` is zero, but what about later when it's non-zero. My point is that you really don't want computed properties performing computationally expensive actions. Re pulling data from the db as soon as the class is instantiated, if you want to do that because the data is small and is easily held in memory, then you could, theoretically do that in `init`, but use a stored property to hold the data, not a computed property to refetch all the data every time you reference that property.

Comment: it will be zero as long as I did not add objects into it. I agree that adding data from db inside computed property is expensive + saving the data inside a stored property will be smarter. However, doing it during init is not possible for me as I am storing class child's inside that array, so if I were to do it during init, it will fail as the child init will try to finish before its parent init finishes. Unfortunately, yet, I don't have an answer of how to do it better. Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: The only reason I suggested `init` is that you asked about pulling data from the db as soon as the class was initiated. But if you don't want to do that, then don't do it in init. And I think you're missing my key point: If you want to retrieve data from the database, then just write a method to retrieve data from the database. All I'm saying is that I would advise against having a computed property do that.

Comment: as you can see in my code, Fruit is a subclass of FruitsPack class so init is not an option for me. However, check out what I did (I edited my question with my solution), I ended up using lazy property.

Comment: Yep, lazily instantiated stored property does it, calling a function to retrieve the data, rather than using a computed property.